# GenerateResource Task generates code for wrong C# Version

Tags: c#, msbuild, portable-class-library

I have a tool that generates resource files (.resx). In order to update the c#-Design file, I need to run the "run custom command" for the .resx-Files.

In order to automate this, I added the GenerateResource task to the build file. This generates the c# file before every compilation.

The code generated with GenerateResource includes following: `typeof(Default).Assembly`. When I run the custom tool command this part is: `typeof(Default).GetTypeInfo().Assembly`.

The resource file is part of a PCL project, in which the type Type does not contain a property Assembly.

The code says it was generated with `"System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "2.0.0.0"` but should have been generated with `"System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0"` instead.

Is there a way to specify the version that should be used by the task? Or another way to automaticly generating these source files without relying on plugins?

Comment: for all that have the same problem. My current workaround is based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837644/how-to-replace-string-in-file-using-msbuild) question. I just replace the not working call with a working one after the code was generate. Ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same situation, GenerateResource needs to be adjusted to use the desired version of the SDK tool resgen.exe. GenerateResource task has a property [SdkToolsPath](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/9435dce9-b114-4b1e-b8a0-3ca4709b4692?category=msbuild), by setting it to e.g. $(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory) might help you.