# Visual Studio Service Fabric Default Deployment Configure File

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

When I `Start Debugging (F5)` in Visual Studio, which configuration file (example: `ApplicationParameters\Local.5Node.xml`) does it use to deploy to my local service fabric cluster?  And more importantly, where is that configured?

---

**Experiment**

I changed my local cluster to 1 node and the deployment (via `F5`) seemed to automatically pick up on this an use `Local.1Node.xml`.  I guess it is querying the cluster?

---

**Real Goal**

My real goal is to create another configuration file `Local.Mike.1Node.xml` and make that the default when I hit `F5`.

Comment: Related SO Post: [Service Fabric Default Publish Profile other than Local.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288717/service-fabric-default-publish-profile-other-than-local-xml/42542173#42542173)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Publish Profile that refers to your custom Application Parameters file `Local.Mike.1Node.xml`. Then you can pass the Publish Profile in the parameter `-PublishProfileFile` to `Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1`.

You'll have to disable automatic deployment, and then call `Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1` with your modified parameter (maybe in a post-build event?).

Honestly though, I think you're better off just modifying the default `Local.1Node.xml` with your custom parameters - you can always recreate a default file by creating a new SF project, or go directly to the project templates themselves.

Comment: I don’t want to have to remember to not commit my changes to git.

Comment: How do I get visual studio to attach the debugger though?  Manually I guess?

Comment: I'm not sure about that one. You might try putting a Debugger.Break() in a strategic location in your code.

Comment: does automatic deployment figure out the number of nodes running in the machine ? (query service fabric to find out ?)