# Is it possible to do text manipulation in csproj?

Tags: c#, csproj

I have the following in my `.csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="Main.qml" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I need to find & replace some text in `Main.qml` on the copy in the published directory. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you explored post-build events in Visual Studio?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837644/how-to-replace-string-in-file-using-msbuild

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. Could you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/) has a `File` class that accepts a `TaskAction` of `Replace`. This action can perform a Regex replace.

You would use it something like this:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File TaskAction="Replace" RegexPattern="input*" Replacement="repl" Path="C:\$(ProjectDir)\$(PublishDir)\Main.qml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<postBuild>
    <Exec command="cmd command to find and replace on file:$(OutputPath)\Main.qml"/>
</PostBuild>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm from the cell phone. Later I will elaborate more.

Comment: I'd like this to be cross-platform, so ideally something using the build tool rather than relying on binaries in the host system.